# check for a condition in a do loop in java

Tags: java, do-while

I created a simple `do while` loop where I want to check a condition ( that the number of characters will be 2 and that both of the characters will be equal).

For some reason if I use the loop with `||` operator it works and if I use the loop with `&&` operator it doesn't work.

I found it hard to understand why the condition works with || and not with &&.

Any idea?

```
        String check;
    do {            

        int num = (int)(Math.random()*200)+10;

        System.out.println(num);

        check = String.valueOf(num);

    } while (check.charAt(0) != check.charAt(1) || check.length() != 2 );
```

Comment: What is the value of `check` ?

Comment: what exactly output u want because u r || condition code which works fine according to u prints 3 digits number also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you've missed to apply a negation somewhere.

If you want to convert your `||`-based expression to a `&&`-based expression, then you'll have to do:

```
while (!(check.length() == 2 && check.charAt(0) == check.charAt(1)));
```

Note that, in order to avoid an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, I'm switching the pieces of the expression, so that we first check the size of the `String`, after which we test the first two characters for equality.

Comment: do you have any idea why it was working with || -expression ?

Comment: Doesn't it would be better if we have while (!(check.length() == 2 && check.charAt(0) == check.charAt(1))); so that in case if the check is empty we wont end up in array index out of bound exception

Comment: @shayyy7, maybe you have missed a negation somewhere, that's why. Try with what's suggested in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition for stopping is length is 2 **and** both characters are equals.

That means: stop when `(check.length() == 2 && check.charAt(0) == check.charAt(1))` Note that it's always better to first check the length since `&&` is a short-circuit operator and otherwise if check's length is smaller than 2, you'll get an exception.

Now, since the condition for the do-while loop is for when to continue looping, you want to negate that (tell the loop when to continue, not when to stop). So you want: `!(check.length() == 2 && check.charAt(0) == check.charAt(1))`.

You can leave it at that, or you can use De-Morgan's law and convert it to a ||-expression: `!(A && B) =~ !A || !B` so for your condition that would be `!(check.length == 2) || !(check.charAt(0) == check.charAt(1))` which is equivalent for `check.length != 2 || check.charAt(0) != check.chatAt(1)`, which is the condition you wrote that works. Since all transitions are iff (if and only if), you can see the equivalent to your || condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an `AND` condition (i.e. `while (check.charAt(0) != check.charAt(1) && check.length() != 2 )`) the loop will exit if either condition fails. Both the first *AND* second conditions must be true for the loop to continue. So if you hit a 2-digit number the loop will exit even if the first two characters match. Similarly if you get a 3 digit number where the first two digits match, the loop will exit. Is this the intended logic?